# Windows 7 delete fingerprint from profile

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, roaming-profile, fingerprint

I'm facing the following situation: I have a computer, joined to an AD with roaming profiles and with fingerprint logon enabled. A problem with a user profile had me delete the said profile and recreate it. The problem is that the fingerprint device does not show any registered fingerprint on the current profile but, when trying to register the same finger it says it cannot be registered. 
I'm assuming that Windows 7 keeps a database of sorts that is not in the user profile directory (since I've deleted it and it still won't let me register the user's finger).
The question is how can I get rid of the database Without reinstalling the whole machine.

The fingerprint reader does not come with any software. Just the drivers. The fingerprint registering is done through the windows 7 gui.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this answer, this may help someone else, you may also try this on *Windows 7*, if the folder is available.

For *Windows 10*:

Try deleting the files from the following folder and then remove the fingerprint

```
C:\Windows\System32\WinBioDatabase
```

and reregister fingerprint and give it a try.